# Vectorization of different dimension

Tags: julia, vectorization

I want to get all permutations of 1:3 as strings.

```
julia> string.(permutations(1:3)...) # 1:3 is for the example, the real problem is larger
3-element Vector{String}:
 "112233"
 "231312"
 "323121"
```

However the result is "transposed" as I want

```
6-element Vector{String}:
 "123"
 "132"
 "213"
 "231"
 "312"
 "321"
```

This vector will be the input of some other (vectorized) function call `F.(perms)` and I want to do this efficiently.
How should I do this?

Comment: Broadcasting, which you call "vectorization", is not so much about efficiency, but about semantics. `string.(permutations(1:3))` should give you the right result, I think, but that is not more efficient than an equivalent loop.

Comment: That does not give the right answer, `string.(zip(permutations(1:3)...)...)` works, or just put it in a loop. However thanks a lot for you note on the efficiency, I actually realize now that handwritten loops are as efficient as nested dot/vectorized function calls. I somehow thought the nested dot calls where more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
julia> join.(permutations(1:3),"")
6-element Vector{String}:
 "123"
 "132"
 "213"
 "231"
 "312"
 "321"
```